# facebook graph api get names on feed

Tags: facebook, api, graph

So I want to use the api but when I use /{event-id}/feed

> I get the follwing: 
>   * message
>   * date
>   * id

But what I also like is the name of the user who posted the message. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You need to specify which fields you want. Read the documentation for which fields that exists

Answer (score 0):

The [API-References](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.7/event/feed) says that you get *An array of Post objects* as result.
These [Post objects](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.7/post) contain detailed information about the message. 
For example the field "from": *Information about the profile that posted the message.*

If the creator of the message is a normal user, *from* will contain an [User object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user). This object contains the fields *first_name* and *last_name*.